# Get the details of data from different table - laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Table: member             Table: loans                       Table: loan_types

id  name  address      id  member_id  loan_types_id  amt      id  name  interest      
1    n1     a1         1     1           2           100       1   nl1    1
2    n2     a2         2     3           1           200       2   nl2    2
3    n3     a3
```

I need to get the data of member that has loan.
The following code gives the data from "member" and "loans" table. Hence loan_types_id is also there. However all of the "loan_types" table details should be included here. How to get that?

Thanks in advance.

Controller: search memberId that has loan

```
public function accountWithLoanSearch(Request $request)
{
    $query = Member::whereHas('loans', function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->get('memberId') != null) {
                $query = $query->where('member_id', $request->get('memberId'));
            }
        })
        ->with('loans')
        ->get();
    return response()->json(json_encode($query));
}
```

Member model

```
class Member extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'address' ];
    
    public function loans() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Loans::class);
    }
}
```

Loans model

```
class Loans extends Model 
{
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
    }
}
```

loanType model

```
class loanType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'loan_types';

    protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'interest' ];
}
```

What I get when member_id = 3 is searched:

```
[{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "n3",
    "address": "a3",
    "loans": {
        "id": 2,
        "member_id": 3,
        "loan_type_id": 1
    }
}]
```

What I need:

```
[{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "n3",
    "address": "a3",
    "loans": {
        "id": 2,
        "member_id": 3,
        "loan_type_id": 1,
        "amt": 200
    },
    "loan_type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "nl1",
        "interest": "1"
    }
}]
```

Comment: try: ->with('loans.loanType')

Comment: it throws error- Call to undefined relationship [loanType] on model [App\\Models\\Loans]

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Loans extends Model 
{
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
    }

    public function loanType() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(LoanType::class, 'id', 'loan_type_id'); 
    }
}
```

And as suggested by @OMR in the comment

controller:

```
public function accountWithLoanSearch(Request $request)
{
    $query = Member::whereHas('loans', function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->get('memberId') != null) {
                $query = $query->where('member_id', $request->get('memberId'));
            }
        })
        ->with('loans.loanType')
        ->get();
    return response()->json(json_encode($query));
}
```